# Autoscaling group on AWS exhausting internal IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-auto-scaling

Suppose I have this simple scenario. I setup an autoscaling group that will launch a new EC2 instance if the CPU usage goes about 85%. My understanding is that when CPU usage goes under a certain level autoscaling group will scale in by reducing the number of EC2 instances. 
Every time an EC2 instance is launched an private IP address is assigned. Suppose my subnet has a CIDR block of 10.0.3.0/28 (which is 16 IPs). 
Questions:
 1. When autoscaling group scale in (remove an EC2 instance) does it release the internal IP to make it available for next time that scales up?
 2. If so, immediately or it takes some time to be released and how long?

Answer (score 1):

1. When autoscaling group scale in (remove an EC2 instance) does it release the internal IP to make it available for next time that scales up?

Of course

2. If so, immediately or it takes some time to be released, and how long?

Well, the time depends on the time that the EC2 is shutting down, you could test this in a AWS account with the free tier, its easy to do it.